# Problemas de Filtrar con Java Date

Tags: java

Estoy intentando filtrar resultados con Java en formato fecha, no se me está permitido usar Select para encontrar los resultados, por eso se me está complicando ...

El problema es que siempre me entra en el if y me guarda los objetos en el array, aunque "mi lógica", no debería permitirle guardarse en el array.

Tengo una serie de registros en la base de datos ->

```
Registro 1-> Fecha Inicio "2018-09-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-09-30"
Registro 2-> Fecha inicio "2018-10-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-10-05"
Registro 3-> Fecha inicio "2017-12-31" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-11-30"
Registro 4-> Fecha inicio "2018-12-01" , Fecha Fin -> "2019-10-01"
Registro 5-> Fecha inicio "2018-12-30" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-12-31"
Registro 6-> Fecha inicio "2018-11-30" , Fecha Fin -> "2018-12-01"
```

El usuario introduce el `"2018-12-01"` hasta el `"9999-31-12"`

- El formato de las fechas son de tipo String "Año-mes-día"
- Mi intención es muestre todos los registros que contengan esa fecha,
  es decir, Debería mostrar el Registro 4,5,6.

El registro 4º debería insertarse al array porque el usuario puso:
`"2018-12-01"` y el registro tiene la misma fecha "2018-12-01"

El registro 5º debería insertarse al array porque el usuario puso:
"2018-12-01" y de fecha de fin año->9999 y el registro está comprendido en su fecha de inicio entre esos valores y ADEMÁS, la fecha de fin, también está comprendida entre esos valores.

El registro 6º porque su fecha de fin corresponde al periodo de tiempo comprendido entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin del usuario, es decir, el usuario quiere entre `"2018-12-01"` hasta el `"9999-31-12"`y la fecha de fin del registro es del `"2018-12-01"`

El registro 1,2,3 no llega ni por fecha de inicio al mínimo del usuario, ni por fecha de fin , al mínimo del usuario.

El código es :

```
@Override
public List<Article> filterResult(String paramSelect, String dateStart, String dateEnd) {

    List<Article> list = null;

    try {
        // Sino me ponen fecha de fin, la establezco al máximo.
        if(dateStart != null && dateEnd == null) {
            dateEnd ="9999-31-12";
            list = (List<Article>) this.pgRepository.findAll();
            list =  this.getStart(list, dateStart, dateEnd);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return list;
}


private List<Article> getStart(List<Article> list, String dateStart, String dateEnd) throws ParseException {

        Date paramStart, paramEnd, userDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateStart) , userEnd  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateEnd);
        List<Article> filter = new ArrayList<Article>();
        Article param;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            param = list.get(i);
            paramStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(param.getStartdatevalidity());
            paramEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(param.getEnddatevalidity());

            if(paramStart.after(userDate) || paramEnd.before(userDate) && paramStart.after(userEnd) ||  paramEnd.before(userEnd)) {
                filter.add(param);
            }
        }

        return filter;
    }
```

Tengo 2 problemas ->

El primero es que siempre se guarda en el array.
El segundo es que no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien la lógica...

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Es Java 8? ¿Se pueden usar lambdas?

Comment: Sí, 1.8, Lambdas no sé que es, he estado mirando y diría que si se puedo usarlo, lo que no puedo es hacer consultas complejas (where ni groupby etc) a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

La condición es un poco más compleja por los casos en el límite pero quedaría algo así:

```
if (paramStart.equals(userDate) || paramEnd.equals(userDate) || paramStart.equals(userEnd) || paramEnd.equals(userEnd)) {
    filter.add(param);
} else if (paramStart.after(userDate) && !paramStart.after(userEnd) && paramEnd.before(userEnd) && !paramEnd.before(userDate)) {
    filter.add(param);
}
```

Lo he probado con esta función:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Range> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add(new Range("2018-09-01", "2018-09-30"));
    dates.add(new Range("2018-10-01", "2018-10-05"));
    dates.add(new Range("2017-12-31", "2018-11-30"));
    dates.add(new Range("2018-12-01", "2019-10-01"));
    dates.add(new Range("2018-12-30", "2018-12-31"));
    dates.add(new Range("2018-11-30", "2018-12-01"));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date paramStart;
    Date paramEnd;
    try {
        Date userDate = sdf.parse("2018-12-01");
        Date userEnd = sdf.parse("9999-31-12");
        int i = 0;
        for (Range date : dates) {
            i++;
            paramStart = sdf.parse(date.start);
            paramEnd = sdf.parse(date.end);
            if (paramStart.equals(userDate) || paramEnd.equals(userDate) || paramStart.equals(userEnd) || paramEnd.equals(userEnd)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            } else if (paramStart.after(userDate) && !paramStart.after(userEnd) && paramEnd.before(userEnd) && !paramEnd.before(userDate)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, ha devuelto el 4º y el 5º, pero no el 6º :(

Comment: Pues yo lo he probado con esta función y sale bien. Te pongo en la respuesta el código con el que he probado